# Remote Desktop Session Broker + Folder Redirection: How to deal with Administrator accounts?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, remote-desktop

We are having a bunch of Windows Server 2008 R2 in a Remote Desktop Session Broker farm to allow access for our employees to a company Remote Desktop. Furthermore folder redirection and roaming profiles are enabled via Group Policy.

How do I handle the Administrator accounts in such a setup? If I only login with my Domain Administrator account is is always redirected to one machine.

If I login with the machine administrator accounts the folder redirection throws errors.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: If you login with any local user account, folder redirection should not happen... that's only applied to domain users.

Comment: How have you applied the policy?  Are you applying the policy per-computer?  Have you setup a loop-back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I only login with my Domain Administrator account is is always redirected to one machine.

Use the `/admin` switch when starting the remote desktop client.  When connecting with that you will be immune to the session broker trying to balance the load on the servers.

> Furthermore folder redirection and roaming profiles are enabled via Group Policy.

Applying roaming-profiles via a group policy is a per-machine setting, that means you are basically setting up a fixed path for roaming profiles for everyone that may use the machine.  The simple solution would just be to make sure that their is a folder withing the roaming profiles path you have set for any account that may login, **including the administrator accounts**.

Folder re-direction is normally a per-user setting, so it doesn't seem like this should be an issue.

Comment: Is it possible to apply roaming profiles as a per-user setting using Group Policy?

Comment: No, unfortunately it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to setup Group Policy as a per-user setting by adding the individual user account to the scope of the group policy in the Group Policy Management Console.  Roaming profiles specifically are able to be applied to individual users using Active Directory Users and Computers by adding the path to the profile tab of the user properties.
Administrator accounts are able to be excluded from folder redirection and roaming profiles by only applying folder redirection to user containers, as opposed to the entire domain.